Help finding an old movie about an alien on a boat?
It's a movie I watched a bit of when I was a child, can't remember exactly when the movie was shown but it was probably made no later than 2005 and probably not before the 90s
I only remember parts of the beginning where a group of people are on a small boat which is sinking, they manage to make it to a larger boat which has a tonne of satellites on it (I assume it's some kind of research vessel?) and most of them make it on board safely except for one guy who gets his leg severely injured due to the pressure of the boat sinking or whatever
Once there, they get attacked by one of the survivors in this suit thing I assume because he thought they might have been taken over by the alien?
The alien itself I remember being fairly small and covered in a metal which it made for itself from the ship. I think I remember it being fairly cheerful and humming as it went about its business (but obviously it ends up killing most of them) 
I just really want to know what this movie is, it gave me so many nightmares as a child! 

Sounds like Virus from 1999 with Jamie Lee Curtis, William Baldwin and Donald Sutherland.

When a typhoon cripples their boat, the crew sails into the eye of the storm, where they discover a high-tech Russian communications and research vessel adrift. Only one Russian crew member is still alive, raving about "intelligent lightning." They soon discover that an alien life form has taken over the ship's computers and is churning out mechanical warriors.

Pretty much everything you've described is there. Here's the trailer:



